# Is there a way to show the Ruby line numbers in javascript generated by Opal

Tags: source-maps, opalrb

For debugging purposes I would like to see the corresponding Ruby Source position in the javascript file generated by Opal.

Is there a simple way to achive this? I tried

```
# config.ru
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

run Opal::Server.new { |s|

  s.append_path 'public'
  s.append_path 'src'
  s.debug = true
  s.source_map = true

  s.main = 'application'

  s.index_path = 'index_opal.html'
}
```

this is my application file

require 'math'
    require 'opal'
    require 'opal-jquery'

```
require 'consolelogger'
require 'harpnotes'
require 'abc_to_harpnotes'
require 'opal-raphael'
require 'opal-jspdf'
require 'opal-jszip'
require 'opal-abcjs'
require 'opal-musicaljs'
require 'raphael_engine'
require 'pdf_engine'
require 'controller'
require 'harpnote_player'
require 'text_pane'

puts "now starting zupfnoter"
puts "zupfnoter
```

I can only see this file in the source maps, but not the ones included by 'require'

I can even set breakpints to the puts statments at the end but nowhere else.

Comment: Have you tried with source maps?

Comment: I tried to but was not able to make it work either. I am still searching for a kind of cookbook how to make that work.

Comment: I see them working in Rails with Chrome but not with Safari (not sure about Firefox). What's your setup?

Comment: I am using primarily chrome. 

     desc "Build our app to build.js"  
     task :build do  
       env = Opal::Environment.new  
       env.append_path "."  
     
       File.open("build.js", "w+") do |out|  
         out << env["application"].to_s  
       end  
     end

Comment: I am using primarily chrome. I generate the JS file with a statement like this: `env = Opal::Environment.new; out << env["application"].to_s`. Where application.rb requires all other rb files. I hope there is an optin for Opal::Environment to be set, but I cannot find it. I tried source_map = true on Opal::Server with out success

Comment: I have an application.rb which does a require to the other Ruby sources. Statements in application.RB appear in the source map while the content of the reqired files do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on how to setup a rack up that serves source maps correctly

https://github.com/opal/opal/tree/0-6-stable/examples/rack (Opal v0.6.x)

---

**UPDATE:** The problem seems to be that you're not in debug mode.

**Explanation:** Current sourcemaps implementation doesn't work with concatenated assets and Sprockets doesn't support sourcemaps natively so it doesn't preserve them during concatenation.

#### Sprockets debug mode with Opal and Rack

To enable debug mode you need to add `debug = true` and use an Erb index.html in Opal::Server:

```rb
# config.ru

run Opal::Server.new do |s|
  s.append_path 'src'
  s.source_map = true
  s.main = 'application'
  s.index_path = 'index.html.erb'
  s.debug = true
end
```

then in your `index.html.erb` you need to use the helper instead of a hardcoded script tag:

```
<%# index.html.erb %>
…
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
…
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried it, but I could not see anything from the sourcemap nor a ruby file in the developer tools neither in Chrome no in Firefox.

Comment: Each JS file has its sourcemap which URL you can find at the end of the compiled file in the form of a special comment. Do you see the special comment?

Comment: this is, what I see there: `//# sourceMappingURL=/__opal_source_maps__/application.js.map
;
`. But I cannot see a file `application.js.map` in `__opal_source_maps__` I even see lots of comments like that in the `application.js` before each class definition. But `__opal_source_maps__` only contains one file `application` which in fact is the same content as application.rb

Comment: when I enter this url, e.g. `http://localhost:9292/__opal_source_maps__/controller.js.map` in the browser adress line, then I can see a lot of cryptic stuff like a source map. Therefore, the opal server seems to deliver the source maps, but I have no clue how to use them in chrome. I expected to see the ruby source there and to be able to set breakpoints.

Comment: **Ok, could it be that you have debug mode turned off in the asset pipeline?**

_Current sourcemaps implementation doesn't work with concatenated assets (that's also due to the fact that the asset pipeline doesn't support sourcemaps natively)._

Comment: Surly this could be. I have added a line to config.ru (intial questions shows my current config.ru): `s.debug=true`(I saw this in https://github.com/opal/opal-rspec). But it has no effect, everything is as it was before.

Comment: Can you share the project or part of it with me so that I can try locally? (I'm `elia` on GitHub and `_elia` on BitBucket.) _In alternative, does the rack example behaves correctly?_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58604/discussion-between-bernhard-and-elia-schito).

Comment: In particular <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> ensures, that javascript is not concatenated but provided as individual assets Great answer.