# Get the error line in a Ruby Opal code

Tags: javascript, ruby, opalrb

```
class Test

  def initialize

  end

  def crash
    print x
  end

end

Test.new.crash
```

Clearly this snippet will crash at line 8. If you parse this with Opal, you will get this compiled code:

```
/* Generated by Opal 0.8.0.beta1 */
(function(Opal) {
  Opal.dynamic_require_severity = "error";
  var self = Opal.top, $scope = Opal, nil = Opal.nil, $breaker = Opal.breaker, $slice = Opal.slice, $klass = Opal.klass;

  Opal.add_stubs(['$print', '$x', '$crash', '$new']);
  (function($base, $super) {
    function $Test(){};
    var self = $Test = $klass($base, $super, 'Test', $Test);

    var def = self.$$proto, $scope = self.$$scope;

    def.$initialize = function() {
      var self = this;

      return nil;
    };

    return (def.$crash = function() {
      var self = this;

      return self.$print(self.$x());
    }, nil) && 'crash';
  })(self, null);
  return $scope.get('Test').$new().$crash();
})(Opal);
```

And of course it will throw the same error.

However, is there a way to determine the **Ruby** line where this error comes from?

I can see this question: [Is there a way to show the Ruby line numbers in javascript generated by Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218609/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-ruby-line-numbers-in-javascript-generated-by-opal), but I don't understand the answer: it leads me to https://github.com/opal/opal/tree/0-6-stable/examples/rack and I'm not sure what am I supposed to be looking at or doing.

When I run my javascript, I have an `index.html` file that loads `opal.min.js` and `opal-parser.min.js`, then finally I have my compiled Ruby-Javascript code in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: The author of the answer @  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218609/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-ruby-line-numbers-in-javascript-generated-by-opal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218609/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-ruby-line-numbers-in-javascript-generated-by-opal) posted an update. You should probably take a look... ;)

Comment: @juliobetta yeah that's what I read. I'm not using Sprockets or Rack or any of that stuff really. I don't even know what that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opal has [source map support](http://opalrb.org/docs/guides/0-8-stable/source_maps.html), to facilitate this kind of source level of debugging. I will not go into details about sourcemaps, but [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com) has a [great article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) that covers the topic in depth.

Here is the minimal boilerplate to set that up with Opal:

Let `index.rb` be our source file:

```
class Test

  def initialize

  end

  def crash
    print x
  end

end

Test.new.crash
```

Since you would rather not use a lot of extraneous utilties, let us directly use the Opal API. Create a file `builder.rb` which will compile the file above:

```
require 'opal'
Opal::Processor.source_map_enabled = true
Opal.append_path "."

builder = Opal::Builder.new.build('index')

# Write the output file containing a referece to sourcemap
# which we generate below : this will help the browser locate the 
# sourcemap. Note that we are generating sourcemap for only code and not
# the entire Opal corelib.
#
File.binwrite "build.js", "#{builder.to_s}\n//# sourceMappingURL=build.js.map"
File.binwrite "build.js.map", builder.source_map.to_s

File.binwrite "opal_lib.js", Opal::Builder.build('opal_lib')
```

Also create an `opal_lib.rb` file containing only:

```
require 'opal'
```

Finally create an `index.html` which will allow us to run the script in browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="opal_lib.js"></script>
    <script src="build.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now to actually compile your file, run:

```
ruby builder.rb
```

This will generate compiled javascript files `opal_lib.js` and `build.js` which are referenced by our `index.html` file. Now just open `index.html` in your browser. You will get a full call-stack and source view:

[image: Opal error stack screenshot]

The line numbers of the source file are available:

[image: Opal error stack trace]

---

As an alternative to using the browser, you can also use Node.js for the same purpose. This requires you have `Node.js` and `npm` installed. You will also need to install npm module `source-map-support`

```
npm install source-map-support
```

Now you can open the node repl and enter the following:

```
require('source-map-support').install();
require('./opal_lib');
require('./build');
```

You will get a stack trace with correct source line numbers  :

```
/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/opal_lib.js:4436
        Error.captureStackTrace(err);
              ^
NoMethodError: undefined method `x' for #<Test:0x102>
    at OpalClass.$new (/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/opal_lib.js:4436:15)
    at OpalClass.$exception (/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/opal_lib.js:4454:31)
    at $Test.$raise (/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/opal_lib.js:4204:31)
    at $Test.Opal.defn.TMP_1 (/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/opal_lib.js:3032:19)
    at $Test.method_missing_stub [as $x] (/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/opal_lib.js:886:35)
    at $Test.$crash (/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/index.rb:8:11)
    at /home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/index.rb:13:10
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gaurav/Workspace/opal-playground/index.rb:13:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

---

I recommend that you use [bundler](http://bundler.io/) for gem management. Here is the `Gemfile` for fetching Opal master:

```
source 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org'

gem 'opal', github: 'opal/opal'
```

To compile you will have to run:

```
bundle install
bundle exec ruby builder.rb
```

Sprockets integration / rack integration that others have mentioned use the same API underneath, abstracting away the plumbing.

---

*Update:*

Since we have the correct line numbers in stack, it is fairly to programatically parse the stack and extract this line number into a variable:

```
require('./opal_lib');
require('source-map-support').install();
var $e = null;
try {
  require('./build');
} catch (e) {
  $e = e;
}
var lines = e.split('\n').map(function(line){ return line.match(/^.*\((\S+):(\d+):(\d+)\)/) })

var first_source_line;

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length ; i++) {
  var match = lines[i];
  if (match == null) continue;
  if (match[1].match(/index.rb$/) {
    first_source_line = match;
    break;
  }
}

var line_number;
if (first_source_line) line_number = first_source_line[2] // ==> 8
```

And of course you can do it ruby as well (but if you are running this in browser you will have to include source-map-support here as well):

```
class Test

  def initialize

  end

  def crash
    print x
  end

end

line_num = nil
begin
  Test.new.crash
rescue => e
  if line = e.backtrace.map{|line| line.match(/^.*\((\S+):(\d+):(\d+)\)/) }.compact.find{|match| match[1] =~ /index.rb$/ }
    line_num = line[2]
  end
end

puts "line_num => #{line_num}" # ==> 8
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way for me to store this line number in a variable? I mean, like, somehow catch the exception in Ruby and store it for later use (instead of just printing it in the browser console)